# MySql : can i query " WHERE '$str' LIKE %table.col% "?

Tags: php, mysql

**Basically i want to add wildcards to the the col value when searching...**

Usually I do this the other way around like this:

```
WHERE cakes.cake_name LIKE '%$cake_search%'
```

however now i want it to match the inverse:

> the user searches for '`treacle
>   sponge`', i want this to match a row
>   where the `cake_name` column  =
>   '`sponge`'.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using MATCH?

```
MATCH(`cake_name`) AGAINST ('treacle sponge')
```

Comment: This requires a FULLTEXT index, which is only available in MyISAM, and not, for example, InnoDB.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as ACCEPTED, if that solves you're problem

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE '$cake_search' LIKE  concat('%',cakes.cake_name, '%')
```

should work. It will need a full table scan but so will the inverse query. Have you looked into [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for MySQL? It will likely make this sort of query more efficient.

Comment: @Haroldo. What is the datatype of your column? If fixed length char you might need to trim spaces before appending the wildcards. `concat('%',trim(cakes.cake_name), '%')`

Comment: Hi Martin, its a VARCHAR 20 whos contents will always be trimmed but could contain a space in the interior ie 'bakewell tart'. Uffo's solution worked fine for me, but ill just try your ammended one tyo satisfy curiousity!

Comment: @Haroldo - Definitely Full Text Search if that's an option for you. My answer is pretty inefficient as it needs to scan every record.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to split the user supplied input on the space character and dynamically construct your query to check the column for those values:

```
$input = "treacle sponge";
$input_words = explode(' ', $input);

$sql_where = "WHERE cakes.cake_name IN('" . implode("','", $input_words) . "')"; // generates: WHERE cakes.cake_name IN('treacle','sponge')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent SQL-Injection, I suggest using prepared statements.

```
$prepStmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE cakes.cake_name LIKE :cake_search
');
if($prepStmt->execute(array('cake_search'=>"%$cake_search%"))) {
 ...
}
```

Or, using full text search:

```
$prepStmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE MATCH (`cake_name`) AGAINST (:cake_search IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
if($prepStmt->execute(array('cake_search'=>$cake_search_words))) {
 ...
}
```

See [JSON specialchars JSON php 5.2.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238855/json-specialchars-json-php-5-2-13) for a complete example.. ;)

Comment: thanks - i plan to upgarde to PDO soon so this will come in handy